# It is possible to run mongoimport from Heroku?

Tags: mongodb, heroku, csv-import

I have a very large dataset of cvs file that need to be regularly imported MongoDB.

I'd like to have the importer run off Heroku and write to a MongoDB Heroku add-on.

mongoimport is a separate binary tool that the MongoDB guys provide.

So, it is possible to run mongoimport off a Heroku dyno?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way to do this with Heroku is with [buildpacks](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks). This is a way of pulling in dependencies and verdored binary builds for use not only in your deployed application but also useful for one off process runs. So probably not just as a dyno.

The buildpack approach is increasingly supported/emulated by other PAAS providers, so it is worthwhile to get acquainted with. There are various examples on [Github](https://github.com/), which is where Heroku pulls in the required buildpack files from. Here are also a few links that should help out with the required repo information and other examples of buildpacks. And yes the client tools are available in a separate package.

http://www.petekeen.net/introduction-to-heroku-buildpacks

https://github.com/kstaken/dockerfile-examples/blob/master/nodejs-mongodb/Dockerfile

https://github.com/fabiokung/heroku-buildpack-fakesu

https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs